# Checking for space in an edittext

Tags: java, android, string, android-edittext

I want to check if there's any space in an edittext. I use this method to get the selected text of edittext:

```
 private String getSelection(EditText editText) {
    int start = editText.getSelectionStart();
    int end = editText.getSelectionEnd();
    Editable edit = editText.getText();
    return edit.toString().substring(start, end);
}
```

But when i do this:

```
if (getSelection(et).getText.toString.contains(" ")) Log.d("TAG","There's a space")
```

contains() will be always false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I think this:**

```
if (getSelection(et).getText.toString.contains(" ")).....
```

**Must be like this:**

```
if (getSelection(et).contains(" ")) .....
```